# Angular 2 Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 401 Unauthorized for URL

Tags: angular, local-storage

I am trying to implement my login function, well its logging in successfully, the problem is that i am getting this error, **Uncaught exception: Response with status: 401 Unauthorized for URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/scrumboard/Recruteurs/** 
(My backend implemented using Django)

login.ts :

```
onSignin(form: NgForm) {
      this.myService.login({username: this.user.username, password: this.user.password})
      .subscribe(
        data =>  {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])}
      );
    }
```

mySercice.ts:

```
public login(user: any){
      const body = JSON.stringify(user);
      let headers = new Headers({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      });

      return this.http.post(this.domain+'/api-token-auth/', body, {
        headers: headers
      })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
                if (token) {
                    this.token = token;
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', body);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
}
```

and here is my Backend logic:
settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

urls.py:

```
router = DefaultRouter();
router.register(r'Recruteurs', RecruteurViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

api.py:

```
class RecruteurViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Recruteur.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecruteurSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

and all my page goes blank .. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I would check the authorization logic on your Back End, the error indicates that your post request is unauthorized for that URL so it does not seem to be an issue with your angular logic.

Comment: Try not sending a string. Also post your route handling in Django.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your post it's not clear that you are sending your JWT token along with your second request. Once you hit login and save your token in local storage, make sure you are properly setting the Authorization header on subsequent requests.

I assume that the request to Recruiters is being made after the router redirects post-login, so look at the service you are calling on the dashboard and ensure it's properly setting the Authorization headers.

Authorization Header Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Additionally, you can set up an interceptor in Angular that will automatically attach the proper headers to every request, and if you get a 401 will redirect the user to the login page.

Tutorial: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8